# removing thumbnails when deleting an uploaded image

Tags: fine-uploader

using Fine-uploader V 3.5  Uploading images successful.
I am displaying the thumbnails of the uploaded images, but how can I delete the thumbnail displays when I delete the file itself?
 Is there an unappend I can perform with the onDeleteComplete callback?

I would think it might be easier to attach it to the right of the file name/size/delete link or immediately below it. Then when the list item is removed, the image is also.

Answer (score 0):

Since Fine Uploader does not yet have the ability to create previews yet (it will soon, see cases [#868](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/868) and [#869](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/869)) I'm assuming you are adding these previews yourself.

So, you simply need to make use of the `onDeleteComplete` callback.  When this callback is invoked, simply remove the associated preview from your document.

Comment: I am using the onComplete callback to display the images as in one of your examples.  Like so:$('#free-images-uploader').append('<img src="<?php echo $baseurl?>images/com_classifiedsredux/ads/originals/<?php echo $frimageIP?>/' + fileName + '" alt="' + fileName + '" style="height:60px; display:inline">&nbsp;');  How do I remove it??

Comment: ...the same way you remove any element from a `document`.  What, specifically are you struggling with?